# I want to print all permutations of 123 in python?

Tags: python, iterator, permutation

123
132
213
231
312
321 
How to get all permutations as a seperate numbers?

Comment: Welcome, It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Look at `itertools.permutations`.

Comment: With [**`itertools.permutations`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: `for i in __import__("itertools").permutations('123'): print int(''.join(i))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to a string with `str()`, use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to get the permutations, finally use a list-comprehension to format the result:

```
[int(''.join(p)) for p in itertools.permutations('123')]
#[123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]
```